# Animating jQuery form ui div after submission

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering how I can animate the jQuery form ui's div update on form submission instead of it plainly appearing.

This is the work I have done so far on my multi-stage form:

http://licf.ronaldboadi.com/practice/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a loading gif while you are processing data and once you have your div ready use a fade in animation.

```
//Assuming you have a $.ajax request to submit the form:

//add the loading gif
$('#submitform').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');

//send your form data
$.ajax({
    url: "process.php",
    data: {
        param1: 1,
        param2: 2,
        param3: 3
    },
    success: function(data){
        //hide the div, assuming the process.php return simple html code to your page update the div content, then add the fade in animation
        $('#submitform').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would I go about achieving this with the target div being called *submitform* which is updated by jQuery form ui?

Comment: Add a simple img element (loading gif) to the div when you submit your form. When you have the result, for example in the success method of an `$.ajax` call, hide the div, replace the img element with the result you got from the server then add the fade in animation.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure where to place the codes can you show me an example please?

Comment: Thanks! But where would I place that code in the context of the jQuery form ui plugin I am using?

Comment: This should be executed in the submit button's click event. I'm not familiar with jquery form ui. Share your code where you submit the form.